# Field 'fieldName' doesn't have a default value in ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, entity

I am having the following entities which are in ManyToMany relation.

`UpdateKeyEntity.java`

```
@Embeddable
public class UpdateKeyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;
    @Column(name = "product_base_version")
    private String productBaseVersion;
    @Column(name = "update_level")
    private int updateLevel;
    @Column(name = "channel")
    private String channel;

   public UpdateKeyEntity() {

    }

    public UpdateKeyEntity(String productName, String productBaseVersion, int updateLevel, String channel) {

        this.productName = productName;
        this.productBaseVersion = productBaseVersion;
        this.updateLevel = updateLevel;
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(this.productName, this.productBaseVersion, this.channel, this.updateLevel);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof UpdateKeyEntity) {
            UpdateKeyEntity updateKeyEntity = (UpdateKeyEntity) obj;
            return this.productName.equals(updateKeyEntity.getProductName()) && this.productBaseVersion.equals(
                    updateKeyEntity.getProductBaseVersion()) && this.channel.equals(updateKeyEntity.getChannel()) &&
                    this.updateLevel == updateKeyEntity.updateLevel;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

`UpdateEntity.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.TABLE_NAME)
public class UpdateEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UpdateKeyEntity updateKeyEntity;
    @Column(name = "files_added", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String filesAdded;
    @Column(name = "files_modified", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String filesModified;
    @Column(name = "files_removed", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String filesRemoved;
    @Column(name = "lifecycle_state")
    private String lifeCycleState;
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "update_level_security_advisories",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "product_name", referencedColumnName = "product_name"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "product_base_version", referencedColumnName = "product_base_version"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "update_level", referencedColumnName = "update_level"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "channel", referencedColumnName = "channel")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sec_ad_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<SecurityAdvisoryEntity> securityAdvisoryEntityList = new HashSet<>();

    public UpdateEntity() {

    }

    public UpdateEntity(UpdateLevelDescription updateLevelDescription) {

        this.updateKeyEntity = new UpdateKeyEntity(updateLevelDescription.getProductName(),
                updateLevelDescription.getProductBaseVersion(), updateLevelDescription.getUpdateLevel(),
                updateLevelDescription.getChannel());
        this.filesAdded = updateLevelDescription.getFilesAdded();
        this.filesModified = updateLevelDescription.getFilesModified();
        this.filesRemoved = updateLevelDescription.getFilesRemoved();
        this.lifeCycleState = updateLevelDescription.getLifeCycleState();

        addSecAdd(updateLevelDescription.getSecurityAdvisoryEntitylist);
    }


    // getter and setters

    private void addSecAdd(List<SecurityAdvisoryEntity> securityAdvisoryEntitylist) {

        for (SecurityAdvisoryEntity securityAdvisoryEntity : securityAdvisoryEntitylist) {
            securityAdvisoryEntityList.add(securityAdvisoryEntity);
            securityAdvisoryEntity.getUpdateEntityList().add(this);
            }   
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(this.updateKeyEntity.getProductBaseVersion(),
                this.updateKeyEntity.getChannel(), this.updateKeyEntity.getUpdateLevel(), this.filesAdded,
                this.filesModified, this.filesRemoved);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof UpdateEntity) {
            UpdateEntity updateEntity = (UpdateEntity) obj;
                 return (updateEntity.getUpdateKeyEntity().getProductBaseVersion().equals(this.
                    getUpdateKeyEntity().getProductBaseVersion()) && updateEntity.getUpdateKeyEntity().getChannel().
                    equals(this.getUpdateKeyEntity().getChannel()) && updateEntity.getUpdateKeyEntity().getUpdateLevel()
                    == this.getUpdateKeyEntity().getUpdateLevel());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`SecurityAdvisoryEntity.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "security_advisories")
public class SecurityAdvisoryEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "securityAdvisoryEntityList")
    private List<UpdateEntity> updateEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "overview", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String overview;

    @Column(name = "severity", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String severity;

    @Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "impact", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String impact;

    @Column(name = "solution", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String solution;

    @Column(name = "notes", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String notes;

    @Column(name = "credits", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String credits;

    public SecurityAdvisoryEntity(SecurityAdvisoryDescription securityAdvisoryDescription) {

        this.id = securityAdvisoryDescription.getId();
        this.overview = securityAdvisoryDescription.getOverview();
        this.severity = securityAdvisoryDescription.getSeverity();
        this.description = securityAdvisoryDescription.getDescription();
        this.impact = securityAdvisoryDescription.getImpact();
        this.solution = securityAdvisoryDescription.getSolution();
        this.notes = securityAdvisoryDescription.getNotes();
        this.credits = securityAdvisoryDescription.getCredits();
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

When executing the following

```
public void persistUpdateLevelDescription(UpdateLevelDescription updateLevelDescription) throws UpdatesException {

    UpdateEntity updateEntity = new UpdateEntity(updateLevelDescription);
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    try {
        persistEntity(updateEntity, entityManager);
        }catch (UpdatesException e) {
                //log and throw
        }
}


private <T> void persistEntity(T entity, EntityManager entityManager) throws UpdatesException {

    int numOfAttempts = 0;
    do {
        numOfAttempts++;
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            return;
        } catch (PersistenceException persistenceException) {
            validatePersistenceException(persistenceException);
        }
    } while (numOfAttempts <= databaseConnection.getMaxRetries());
    throw new UpdatesException("Database connection failed when inserting the provided entity");
}
```

I am getting the following error,

```
2020-04-26 21:38:24 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2020-04-26 21:38:24 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - Field 'updateEntity_product_name' doesn't have a default value
2020-04-26 21:38:24 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:193 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2020-04-26 21:38:24 ERROR ExceptionMapperStandardImpl:39 - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]
2020-04-26 21:38:24 ERROR UpdatesException:29 - Database connection failed when inserting 10 update level of wso2i2-5.7.0
org.kasun.updates.updatesms.exception.UpdatesException: Database connection failed when inserting 10 update level of wso2i2-5.7.0
    at org.kasun.updates.updatesms.dao.UpdatesRepository.persistUpdateLevelDescription(UpdatesRepository.java:337)
    at org.kasun.updates.updatesms.UpdatesManager.persistUpdateLevelDescriptions(UpdatesManager.java:142)
    at org.kasun.updates.updatesms.service.UpdatesService.updateInformation(UpdatesService.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.router.HttpMethodInfo.invokeResource(HttpMethodInfo.java:187)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.router.HttpMethodInfo.invoke(HttpMethodInfo.java:143)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.dispatchMethod(MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.java:218)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.lambda$onMessage$57(MSF4JHttpConnectorListener.java:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.kasun.updates.updatesms.exception.UpdatesException: Exception occurred while connecting to the database
    at org.kasun.updates.updatesms.dao.UpdatesRepository.validatePersistenceException(UpdatesRepository.java:740)
    at org.kasun.updates.updatesms.dao.UpdatesRepository.persistEntity(UpdatesRepository.java:451)
    at org.kasun.updates.updatesms.dao.UpdatesRepository.persistUpdateLevelDescription(UpdatesRepository.java:332)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
    at org.kasun.updates.updatesms.dao.UpdatesRepository.persistEntity(UpdatesRepository.java:448)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:56)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2934)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3434)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1397)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'updateEntity_product_name' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 32 more
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you write equals() and hashCode() methods for your UpdateKeyEntity and test if it works?

Comment: @Guardian thanks for the input, but it did not work. I have updated the question with those method overrides.

Comment: Can you make sure every field in every embedded Id is not null? or provide default values in case they are not field later on. since when you use @Embeddable , every field has not null constraint. By the way, the reason i asked to implement the equals and hashCode was that your embeddable class is used as an ID and you need proper way of comparing two ids together.

Comment: @Guardian set default values, still the same error. Does the way I have added the composite key of `UpdateEntity` in `jointable` is correct,  cant this be due to the use of composite keys

Comment: I am pretty sure they are correct. how did you specify default values? inside constructor? you have to do it in both constructors. Did you have any null values for fields inside your embeddable? just replace any null value inside with a default. I quite sure it fixes ur problem.